# PHP not executing shell script and overloading apache

Tags: php, bash, shell, sudo

I want to execute my book generator script with php.

I tried to run my script on my linux terminal and all worked out fine.

```
  sudo /home/repoadmin/apple/arduino.raamatu.generaator.sh
```

I used some execute function from stackoverflow to see what it echos during execute(also tried regular exec() and shell_exec()):

```
function liveExecuteCommand($cmd)
{

while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen("$cmd 2>&1 ; echo Exit status : $?", 'r');

$live_output     = "";
$complete_output = "";

while (!feof($proc))
{
    $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
    $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
    echo "$live_output";
    @ flush();
}

pclose($proc);

// get exit status
preg_match('/[0-9]+$/', $complete_output, $matches);

// return exit status and intended output
return array (
                'exit_status'  => intval($matches[0]),
                'output'       => str_replace("Exit status : " . $matches[0], '', $complete_output)
             );
}

define('__FILEDIR__','/home/repoadmin/apple');
    chdir(__FILEDIR__);
    readdir(__FILEDIR__);
    liveExecuteCommand("sudo /home/repoadmin/apple/arduino.raamatu.generaator.sh");
    closedir(__FILEDIR__);
```

I added `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/home/repoadmin/apple/arduino.raamatu.generaator.sh` to /etc/sudoer for executing with sudo.

My apache2 server freezes when I'm executing this php. When I restart my apache2, the output what I get is this:

```
/home/repoadmin/apple/arduino/arduino_raamat.pdf Could not open input file: /home/www/xxx/xxx/bookcreator.php?lang=et&toc=arduinotoc&book=book --2017-07-14 15:34:11-- http://xxx.xxx.xx/bookcreator.php Resolving xxx.xxx.xx (xxx.xxx.xx)... 195.xxx.xxx.xxx Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx (xxx.xxx.xx)|195.xxx.xxx.xxx|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: unspecified [text/html] Saving to: '/home/repoadmin/apple/bookcreator_output.html' 0K .
```

**What could be the problem and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` to run the script?

Comment: I need it because some files need that permission and I cant change that